# my top bar isn't filling completely

Tags: html, css

My top bar on my website isn't completely changing color... there is a sliver at the bottom. Does anyone know why? My [website](http://reteps.github.io) and the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmoVh.jpg). My code:

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://github.com/reteps" >Github</a></li>
    <li> <a href="gradecalc/gradecalc.html" >Grade Calculator</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header ul { /*selects list of stuff*/
  list-style-type: none; /*no bullet points*/
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #70deef;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
header li { /*selects list element*/
  float: left; /*move to left*/
}
header li a { 
  display: block; /*makes a square*/
  color: #ffffff; /*white*/
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 10px;
}
header li a:hover {
  background-color: #d6d6d6; /*grey*/

}
```

Comment: Your `ul` has a height of 50. The child `li`'s are only as tall as the text and the padding. Remove the `ul` height.

Comment: Should I put the height inside the `li` tag?

Comment: Just remove the height from the `ul` class. Let the padding and text height control the header height.

Comment: Thanks! it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove height on `ul` tag. Your block height is already being determined by content `font-size` and `padding` (plus margin/border if any)

Answer (score 0):

In case of ul tag, never go for height attribute.
Since it can cause unnecessary gaps.

```
ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

This is the minimum but sufficient styling for ul tag